# To return the value from foreach loop in string while parsing XML String

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

Below is my Code for XML parsing:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
// string storing my XML  result from Web Service
xmlDoc.LoadXml(periodID_Value_Before_OffSet); 
string xpath = "//ResultSetHierarchy/object/measure.values/series";
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);
foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode
  ("//ResultSetHierarchy/object/measure.values/series/value").Value);
}
```

Here, I have parsed the XML string which is the output that resulted from web service.
Below is the result from the webservice

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<ResultSetHierarchy totalResultsReturned="1" totalResults="1" firstIndex="0" 
maxCount="-1"> 
 <object id="SC.1938773693.238">
  <measure.values> 
   <series id="SC.1938773693.108280985"> 
      <value periodid="SC.1938773693.394400760" value="17" /> 
      <value periodid="SC.1938773693.1282504058" value="15" />
      <value periodid="SC.1938773693.1631528570" value="13" /> 
   </series> 
  </measure.values>
 </object> 
</ResultSetHierarchy>
</string>
```

I want to get the values of all **periodid** in different variables from ForEach loop used while parsing the string, since I want to store this values in file, when I am not using ForEach loop then I can read only one value that is **17**, I want to get all the values from periodid, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(periodID_Value_Before_OffSet); // string storing my XML 
var items = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");
var xmlActions = new string[items.Count];
var xmlActionsone = new string[items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    var xmlAttributeCollection = items[i].Attributes;
    if (xmlAttributeCollection != null)
    {
        var periodid= xmlAttributeCollection["periodid"];
        xmlActions[i] = periodis.Value;
        var value= xmlAttributeCollection["value"];
        xmlActionsone[i] = value.Value;
        string values = "";
        values += periodid.Value + "," + value.Value;
    }
}
```

This code will read the count of period id.
Then it will loop according to the count and will fetch the values. 
Then it will be appended to a string using the commas in between them. 
At the end you just split the string and get the values.

To split the values..

```
string counts = values;
string[] periods= counts.Split(',');
string value1=periods[0];
string value1=periods[1];
string value1=periods[2];....
```

Now you have all values in respective variables..

Comment: Hope it helps..If cleared your problem,mark it as answer else comment here, I will clear your doubts..

Comment: xmlActions[i] = action.Value;... at this line ,its giving me error as System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Sasidharan... Thanks it works, I checked with syntax and data and it worked perfectly.. Thank You.

Comment: @Sasidharan.. can you plz tell me in your code , how I can return the multiple values from for loop since I want to take the values in array, actually here in your code I have to explicitly mention the number of value to take the period value but I want the values should obtained as long as period is available, I don't want to declare fixed no of periods,plz..if you can modify your code, it will be of great help.

Comment: @sasidharan... here in your code I am getting only Period Id cant I get its value also against the particular Id like this period:value..so that I can come to know which value belongs to which periodid..

Comment: declare another variable and xmlattributecollection..Now append PeriodId and value together..Then split it..

Comment: Then get the arraylength..based upon length get or assign the values..Hope u got it

Comment: ..actually I don't understand how to append the value and split it, trying for it, can you please update in the code since I am in great need now..thank you

Comment: @Sasidharan... If I intend to get series id I am getting error as Object reference not set to an instance of an object since there is space between series and id, can't I use series id to get the id value, do know any method that can deal with this problem. and yes, your updated anser worked great..Thanks a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40939/discussion-between-sasidharan-and-reshma)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something along:

```
var vals = childrenNode.Element("series") 
           .Elements() 
           .Select(element => element.value);
```

I'll try to give it a run on visual studio, but that should work.

---

This should do what you ask:

```
foreach (XmlNode seriesNode in nodes)
{

    var valueNodes = seriesNode.ChildNodes;
    foreach (XmlNode valueAttribute in valueNodes)
    {
        var holdsYourValue = valueAttribute.Attributes["value"].Value;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Value: " + holdsYourValue);
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode
        ("//ResultSetHierarchy/object/measure.values/series/value").Value);    
}
```

Comment: @Noctics.. sorry, can you please provide me sample example which can execute as above said by you, I am new to this concept so I am not able to program it syntactically right, it's giving me error.

Comment: @Reshma Let us know what the error is, what Noctis wrote should be correct LINQ to XML.

Comment: @Noctics.. I am getting error for .Elements as System.XML.XMLNode does not contain definition for element and no extension method element accepting a first argument of type System.XML.XMLNode could be found... It Seems I need to use XDocument instead of XMLDocument, can you provide me piece of code which will use the XDocument and retrieve the data by using the method explained by you,